# How to use Open Street Map with React-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, dictionary, openstreetmap, react-native-maps

As beginner in react-native, I'm looking for a library in react native that may support map visualization (Open street Map) on react-native.

Therefore I found out :
[react-native-open-street-map](https://github.com/Multiware-Tecnologia/react-native-open-street-map) -- but this works only for android,
[react-native-webview-leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview-leaflet) -- but no more supported since 2years.
Have you alternative solutions that may help me ?

Please, I'm avoiding Google Maps, I need a priceless solution.

Comment: Hello! Have you found a solution how to use open street map?

Comment: yes I found a mean to use it.

Comment: What solution did you came up with ? Please tell.

Comment: I have loaded the leaflet map in a webview, and via the prop injectedJavaScript, I added some interactions to the map.

Answer (score -2):

would suggest go for https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps
as this is much maintainable library then previous one and then use it as follows

```
import MapView, {Marker, Callout, PROVIDER_GOOGLE} from 'react-native-maps';
getInitialState() {
  return {
    region: {
      latitude: 37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    },
  };
}

onRegionChange(region) {
  this.setState({ region });
}

render() {
  return (
    <MapView
      region={this.state.region}
      onRegionChange={this.onRegionChange}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the guide.